# Lenovo T500 with Windows 8 : black screen with cursor

Tags: windows-8

I'm having this problem on my Lenovo T500 running Windows 8 Pro x64 with latest ATi drivers installed on.

When I try to boot from shut down state the screen looks black and when I try to move the cursor I see it coming as if there's another screen switched on.

After managing to log in blindly , Windows 8 boots on Extended screen and every time I've to navigate through Win + K -> Second Screen -> PC Screen Only.

This happens always, every time I load Windows, when I use ATi GPU.

This is not happening when I'm using the Intel's GPU with Microsoft's drivers.

Need help or an advice how to fix that problem. I've tried finding solution everywhere but without any luck.

- should I use older , but specific drivers for ATi

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using Lenovo System update, that make all available driver up-to date, you can download from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE).
2. Did Windows 8 automatically recognize your graphic card driver? what happened if you are using on that mode? aby black screen?